# Where does graylog save dashboard / widget design?

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I want to backup the design of my graylog dashboard and specific widgets. Where does graylog store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored in mongodb. You can have a look at the architecture [here](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.2/pages/architecture.html#bigger-production-setup)

Here there is a [link](https://www.slideshare.net/Graylog/graylog-engineering-design-your-architecture) to the detailed architecture. look at the 8th slide. It shows that all the metadata related to dashboards are stored in mongodb

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer this rather old question of mine, appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Best way to backup dashboard is to use `Content Pack`. Create your own content pack select desired dashboards, and it will create json extract, which you can use as backup. You can than use content pack to import dashboard to same or another instance of graylog.

https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.3/pages/content_packs.html